# Show that $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$

Tags: interval-arithmetic

> Let $a<b$ and $c<d$ be real numbers. Show that $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$.

I don't understand the question. Since $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are intervals, what does it mean to add them?

Comment: Unless context makes it explicit otherwise, I read them being points-as-vectors, not intervals.

Comment: @Nij My teacher said intervals.

Comment: It means adding each number on the first interval with each number in the second.

Comment: Okay. Suppose you take a number from (a,b) and add it to a number from (c,d). What values could the result possibly be?

Comment: http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/bph-publications/AmSci-2003-11-Hayes-interval.pdf

Comment: @Nid: It would be as in the O.P.'s question since addition preserves inequalities.

Comment: I think (a,b) + (c,d) = {x + y| x $\in$ (a,b) and y $\in$ (c,d)}.  This boils down to showing if a < x < b and c < y < d then a+b < x + y < c+d and if a+b < z < c + d then there exist u and w such that z = u + w and u in (a,b) and w in (c,d).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The set inclusion $(a,b) + (c,d)\subset (a+c, b+d)$ is easy to prove. The reverse inclusion is trickier. For the reverse inclusion, first prove the simpler case $a=c=0$, then apply this result to the general case, using the identity
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=\{a\}+(0,b-a)+\{c\} + (0,d-c).$$

Answer (score 0):

In terms of sets and set notation:

$(a,b)$ = all the points of R that are between a and b exclusively =$\{x\in \mathbb R| a < x < y\}$

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, than we say $A + B =\{x+y|x \in A; y \in B \}$.

So the statement $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+b,c+d)$ means that $(a,b) + (c,d)=\{x+y|a <x <b;c <y<d\}$ is the same as $(a+b, c+d) = \{z|a+b <z <c+d\}$

Proof:

1) if $z=x+y \in (a,b) + (c,d)$, that is, $a <x <b;c <y <d$ then $a+c <x+y <b+d$ so $(a,b)+(c,d) \subset (a+c,b+d) $.  That was easy.

2) if $z \not \in (a+b,c+d)$

a) if $z \le a + c$.  Let $x$ be any number such that $a < x < b$.  Then if  $z =x+y$ for some $y$ it follows that $y = z-x < a+c-a =c$ so $z \not \in (a,b) +(c,d)$.

b) Likewise if $z \ge b + d$.  Let $y$ be any number such that $c < y < d$.  Then if  $z =x+y$ for some $x$ it follows that $x = z-y > b+d-d =b$ so $z \not \in (a,b) +(c,d)$.

So $z \not \in (a+b,c+d)$ implies $z \not \in  (a,b)+(c,d)$.

So $(a,b)+(c,d) \subset (a+b,c+d)$

1 and 2 together mean $(a+b,c+d)=(a,b)+(c+d)$.

Comment: It would appear you've fallen victim to HTML, by placing a 'less than' symbol next to a piece of text.

Comment: I thought I had caught most of those.  I was typing from my phone so LaTex was a pain and I mostly tried to avoid it.   Where am I missing one?

Answer (score -2):

Let function $f : [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (x,y) := x + y$$

We can find the *minimum* and *maximum* of $f$ by solving two linear programs, namely,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x+y\\ \text{subject to} & a \leq x \leq b\\ & c \leq y \leq d\end{array}$$

and

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x+y\\ \text{subject to} & a \leq x \leq b\\ & c \leq y \leq d\end{array}$$

Since $\nabla f (x,y) = 1_2$, we conclude that:

- the minimum of $f$ is $a+c$, which is attained at $(x,y) = (a,c)$.
- the maximum of $f$ is $b+d$, which is attained at $(x,y) = (b,d)$.

Thus, interval addition is defined as follows

$$[a,b] + [c,d] := [a+c,b+d]$$

Comment: The question does refer to open intervals though..And a definition of interval arithmetics already exists, no need to invent a new one.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Then use 
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{supremize} & x+y\\ \text{subject to} & a < x < b\\ & c < y < d\end{array}$$

Comment: Nope, just use the standard definition: $X+Y=\{x+y|x\in X,y \in Y\}$

Comment: What bounds? First of all we are refering to open sets of reals, as the OP asked.

Comment: Which is irrelevant to the question. Again, you answer based on a definition of your own, not the standard interval arithmetic, while ignoring the fact that the question refers to open intervals. Also, why do you call them "programms"?

Comment: Oh, I don't have any special bond with that definition..And certainly, no love for it..